# Android splash screen image that occupies full screen width and height

Tags: android, image, dpi

I am trying to create a splash screen image that scales well for each screen size.

I am trying to determine if I am misunderstanding how pixel densities function.

According to the [documentation](https://developer.android.com/training/multiscreen/screendensities.html),

> To create alternative bitmap drawables for different densities, you
>   should follow the 3:4:6:8:12:16 scaling ratio between the six primary
>   densities. For example, if you have a bitmap drawable that's 48x48
>   pixels for medium-density screens, all the different sizes should be:
>
> 36x36 (0.75x) for low-density (ldpi)
>   48x48 (1.0x baseline) for medium-density (mdpi)
>   72x72 (1.5x) for high-density (hdpi)
>   96x96 (2.0x) for extra-high-density (xhdpi)
>   144x144 (3.0x) for extra-extra-high-density (xxhdpi)
>   192x192 (4.0x) for extra-extra-extra-high-density (xxxhdpi)

Now, I take this to mean that a 192x192 image will occupy the same amount of screen space on an xxxhdpi display as a 48x48 pixel image on a standard display.

That means that if I want a full screen image for a Google Pixel 2 display which is 1080px by 1920px and has an xxhdpi density of 2.6 then I need an image that is 1080 * 2.6 = 2808px by 1920 * 2.6 = 4992px.

Is this logic correct?